# Upgrade Ubuntu server 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS No candidate ver

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, 20.04, lts

If I try to update my upgrade my Ubuntu server 18.04.5 LTS installation to 20.04.1 LTS, the release updater tool lists ALL of my packages as `No candidate ver:  xxx`, so no package would be updated.

```
Reading cache

Checking package manager

.
.
.

No candidate ver:  zypper
No candidate ver:  zypper-common
No candidate ver:  zypper-doc
No candidate ver:  zytrax
No candidate ver:  zziplib-bin
No candidate ver:  zziplib-bin:i386
No candidate ver:  zzuf
No candidate ver:  zzuf:i386

Do you want to start the upgrade?


23 installed packages are no longer supported by Canonical. You can
still get support from the community.

51 packages are going to be removed.

 Continue [yN]  Details [d]
```

**Edit:** Maybe it lists all of the packages, not just the installed. For example `zypper` is not installed according to `dpkg`.

Comment: zypper is a Red Hat tool. Are you sure your server is not OpenSue, Fedora etc ? Those packages are usually not found on an Ubuntu Server. What does `cat /etc/lsb-release` say?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure. :) `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"`. That's just the end of the list, it lists all of the installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was my fault. I had a pin in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` for focal with negative priority.